# ubuntu - can not find shared library while compiling

Tags: linux, boost, compilation

I would like to compile code with such a statement:

```
 c++ -I /usr/boost_1_53_0 boost_test.cpp -o boost \ /usr/lib/boost/libboost_regex.a
```

but it throws

```
c++: error:  /usr/lib/boost/libboost_regex.a: No such file or directory
```

I am sure, that libboost_regex.a is existing i above mentioned directory.
How to solve it? I am new to ubuntu and linux.
Looking forward for your tips. Thanks.

Comment: What output do you get for `ls -la /usr/lib/boost/libboost_regex.a`?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2627884 cze 25 11:11 /usr/lib/boost/libboost_regex.a

Comment: Do you also have the backslash ("\") included in your command line? If it is a single line, you would end up searching for `<blank>/usr/lib/boost/libboost_regex.a` - can you try to remove the backslash?

Comment: solved :), the problem was the above mentioned backslash "\". Thanks and sorry for such a newbie question, I have to get used to linux...

Comment: @andreas looks to be on the right path - there are 2 spaces in the error message, and the standard error message is `error:` with a single space to the message

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the backslash included in the command line:

```
c++ -I /usr/boost_1_53_0 boost_test.cpp -o boost \ /usr/lib/boost/libboost_regex.a
                                                  ^
                                                  +-- escaped space character
```

This backslash escapes the following space character, so that effectively the path name is (using [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for better readability):

```
%20/usr/lib/boost/libboost_regex.a
```

To solve it, simply remove the backslash character.